# Angular2 - Simple changes QueryList

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get simple changes on a QueryList? I have a list of childcomponents which I hold in a querylist. I want to check which childcomponent has been added to the list (in an onchange event).

Parentcomponent:

```
   @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => ChildComponent), { descendants: true })
    private childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

When I click on a button a childcomponent gets added to the dom so the querylist changes triggers.

When I subscribe to the querylist like so:

```
this.childComponents.changes.subscribe((changes) => {
        //here i just get the updated list. I don't have the previous list to compare.
});
```

Comment: some code will be helpful if you have tried something.

Comment: I've added some code.

Answer (score 2):

a list `QueryList` has `changes` event, you could subscribe to it. then you could using `IterableDiffers` for compare

Parentcomponent:

```
@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => ChildComponent), { descendants: true })
private childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

constructor(private differs: IterableDiffers) {
    this.differ = this.differs.find([]).create(null);
}
```

// in some method

```
this.childComponents.changes.subscribe((changes) => {
    let changeDiff = this.differ.diff(changes);
    if (changeDiff) {
      changeDiff.forEachAddedItem((change) => { // added item
      });
      changeDiff.forEachRemovedItem((change) => { // removed item
      });
    }
});
```

Online Demo for sample accordion: https://plnkr.co/edit/1xNOvp?p=preview

Open your console to see result

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/IterableDiffers-class.html